# CKEDITOR.styleSet.add - new style for 'a' element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

For some reason if I change `'p'` to `'a'`, it no longer appears on the style list. Any reason why?

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('default',[ 
        { name : 'Wys wiersza 1' , 
          element : 'p', 
          styles : { 'line-height' : '18px' } 
         }
]);
```

-edited the code, I missed some brackets while copying

Comment: don't know about your question, but theres a `)` missing, maybe that helps?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a bracket mess. This code will work:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'default',
    [
        {
            name: 'Wys wiersza 1' ,
            element: 'p',
            styles: { 'line-height' : '18px' }
        }
    ]
);
```

EDIT: Now I see it's a CKEditor bug as it only fails for `element: 'a'`. Created ticket for this: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9349